# Creating a sample of huge collection in mongodb to test queries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a huge collection of tweets downloaded by someone else and I want to test an `aggregate()` query on that. But, it takes a lot of time to execute and I want to quickly check my results.

Can I create a smaller sample collection using the huge original collection so that I can test new queries on that quickly? If yes, how can I do that? If no, how do people usually test the correctness of the query before execution?

All the answers I found till now say about dumping the entire collection while I just want a sample of it to run my `aggregate()` query. I've tried doing a `db.collection.findOne().aggregate(/*QUERY*/)` but it throws an error saying that `aggregate is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily create a subset of your collection like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate({$limit: 1000}, {$out: "subsetCollection"})
```

this will take 1000 results from yout original collection and write the to a new collection named "subsetCollection". 
You can then test your aggregation queries on this new collection